# Cannot build DLL with base class

Tags: c++, dll, linker-errors, compiler-warnings

To make it very short,
1. I am building a DLL (dynamic) in VC++ 2010 
2. I have two classes which I want to export
  a) Class A which is base class
  b) Class B which inherits A
3. These are in two separate files  ClassA.h and ClassB.h Both implementation are in their respective cpp files and are under the same project
4. I have the following symbols in both header files

```
#ifdef COLLECTIONS_LIB
#define COLLECTIONS_LIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define COLLECTIONS_LIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

1. Class A has one virtual function, calculate()
2. These two classes are under the `namespace` CollectionsLib

Now whenever I build I the warnings LNK4217

```
locally defined symbol ??ClassA@CollectionsLib@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall CollectionsLib::Class::~Class(void)) imported in function __unwindfunclet$??0ClassA@CollectionsLib@@QAE@V?$Point_@H@cv@@HHV?$Scalar_@N@3@HI@Z$0
```

I just dont understand why it is showing me this error. Why the destructor?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the definition of that destructor. Likely you'll find it in two or more places or in the haeder.

This warning is issued when you have a function __declspec(dllimport) but a non-inline body is defined, or __declspec(dllexport) and multidefined.